# Div to fill the empty space left height

Tags: html, css

I have this sample:

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/keat2qp3/1/)

**CODE HTML:**

```
    <div id="wrap">

      <div class="nav">
        <ul>
          <li>Link1</li>
          <li>Link2</li>
          <li>Link3</li>
          <li>Link4</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        asdasdsa
      </div>

    </div>

    <footer>

    </footer>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
   #wrap{
    float: none;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 348px);
}
.nav{
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
  width:200px;
  height:100%;
  background:red;
}
.right{
  background:blue;
  width:calc(100% - 200px);
  float:left
}

footer{
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  background:grey;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
```

What I want to do is the div's on the left side to give it to the footer height.

Can you please tell me what is wrong with my code?

Div (red) basically want to be up to footer.I managed to do this with `display: table` but I want another solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/keat2qp3/2/).
Modify your `.nav` code as below

```css
#wrap {
  float: none;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 348px);
}
.nav {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
}
.right {
  background: blue;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  float: left
}
footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: grey;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">

  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>Link1</li>
      <li>Link2</li>
      <li>Link3</li>
      <li>Link4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    asdasdsa
  </div>

</div>

<footer>

</footer>
```

Comment: It is perfect but please tell me where does the value of 50px?

Comment: It's the height of `footer`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/keat2qp3/4/)**

CSS:

```
html, body {
  height:100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}
#wrap{
    float: none;
    height: calc(100vh - 50px);
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 348px);
}
.nav{
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
  width:200px;
  height:100%;
  background:red;
}
.right{
  background:blue;
  width:calc(100% - 200px);
  float:left
}

footer{
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  background:grey;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
```